# Required headers and api version to make http requests to AWS service actions (Cloudwatch logs) createLogStream and putLogEvents without AWS-SDK?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, web-frontend, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

To be precise, In order to make api requests to aws services over http, one must sign the requests using Sigv4 process(recommended by aws, described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html ). It has a sophisticated procedure in which the http request headers must be included in sign. I've added the essential headers for signing through Authorization header for [createLogStream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogStream.html) action of Cloudwatch logs service,

```
'Host': 'logs.<region>.amazonaws.com',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
'X-Amz-Date': <AMZ_DATE>,
'X-Amz-Target':  Logs_20140328.CreateLogStream,
'X-Amz-Content-Sha256': <PAYLOAD_HASH>,
```

And making a Http request to [https://logs.{region}.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateLogStream&version={version}](https://logs.%7Bregion%7D.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateLogStream&version=%7Bversion%7D) from the frontend application.

However, the following response error (400) occurs,

```
message: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
__type: "InvalidSignatureException"
```

I have checked the secret access key and the signed headers, they were fine;
If I remove `Content-Type` header, I get a successful 200 response, but the response results in

```
{Output: {__type: "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException", message: null}, Version: "1.0"}
```

One of the solutions to fix this issue recommends to add the `Content-Type` header ([com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException when triggering CodeBuild from API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546226/com-amazon-coral-serviceunknownoperationexception-when-triggering-codebuild-fro)).

Should `Content-Type` header be included? Would be great if any help on what headers must be included and the specific api version for Cloudwatch logs to be set ?

Thanks in advance!!!